# module.run not executing in state.highstate, but works with state.sls

Tags: salt-stack

I'm attempting to re-run a state from another state.  I'm not using `watch` or `watch_in` etc b/c i want it to run each time.  I configure all my nginx virtual hosts and then at the end another state runs called `nginx-certs` the relevant portion is here:

```
nginx-frontend:
  module.run:
    - name: state.sls
    - mods:
      - nginx-frontend
```

During the highstate i see the state_id is executed but has no comments, nor shows it reruns that state, it just completes as `Result: True`.  I can then jump to the salt master and run
`sudo salt webserver state.sls nginx-certs`
and when it hits nginx-frontend, it does reload all of the virtual hosts, putting the new cert in the config.

I'm curious why this does not run in the highstate.

I have attempted ll sorts of different variations of the simple block outlined above.  This one works, but not in the highstate, which is my goal to fix.

If you wonder why i do it this way, all certificates for production and staging terminate at HAProxy and nginx only serves up 80/http1 81/h2, but when building out dev servers i want to assign the cert directly to the server as it will be public facing.  I need to build out the virtual hosts first to get port 80 open which is used for lets-encrypt. Then when the cert is available, update the nginx vhosts listen directive and cert paths.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to do. Are you working on a single server (or multiple times the same server) or do you want to run state on one server and have another one reconfigure?

Comment: A single that are built on demand, all of the virtual hosts will be created on the one server with port 80 open, the `nginx-certs` state is run last and after the cert is obtained from lets encrypt the virtual hosts have to be updated to now listen on 443.  I want it to run each time b/c if the servers last more than 90 days, they will need a new cert. hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand: you have one server which you want temporarily configured with Nginx on port 80, then generate its certificate with letsencrypt, then change Nginx configuration to be on port 443.

What you can do is:

- have one state which installs and configures Nginx to listen on port 80
- have another state with installs/configures/runs letsencrypt
- a third state which configures Nginx as you want it to be at the end [1]
- you just include them in salt to be run in the specific order like

```
# custom_nginx.sls

include:
  - temp_nginx_on_port_80
  - letsencrypt_cert
  - nginx
```

[1] for this I think its better to use formula like the one from the community https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/nginx-formula/ and configure it with pillar data. Obviously if you use it for step 3, you won't be able to use for step 1 *(or at least I don't see right now how)*